# How much spam traffic does this site get?

Tags: discussion, statistics

This is just idle curiosity on my part after seeing another pair of spammers lurch in here trying to get links back to their site (and getting removed within minutes). I'm guessing they come *here* of all places because there's a lot of traffic to Stack Exchange, and that there's a lot more than a pair of fresh accounts offering face creams. So, how much spam traffic does Sec.Se get every month?

Comment: The people behind the Smoke Detector chatbot, that detects spam, keep some data about the spam it encounters. I believe the dataset is called Metasmoke. Smoke Detector can be found in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chatroom.

Comment: S.L.Barth mentions that MetaSmoke contains the dataset, this dataset can be found here: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?site=Information+Security This dataset is not a full list of received spam, only SE and/or moderators can see this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll expand on the comments by S.L. Barth and Ferrybig. Here is the [list of 100 most recent spam posts](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=Information+Security&feedback=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) (with a few false positives mixed in), as reported by [SmokeDetector bot](https://github.com/charcoal-se/smokedetector/wiki). According to it, the average is about 5 spam posts per day: more during the business days, fewer during the weekend. (There may have been some spam that SmokeDetector failed to report.)

[Metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/graphs), the web dashboard for SmokeDetector, shows the distribution of spam reports by site:

[image: metasmoke]

There are Big Five sites with lion's share of spam: SO, SU, Drupal, AU, and Meta. After that, there is everybody else - and Information Security is the top of that group.

The above only reflects the traffic that succeeded in posting. A lot more spam [gets blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228043), but we don't have a count of those attempts; I don't think even moderators do. See [Could moderators be given access to how much spam their site(s) see?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244950)

Comment: It would be interesting to see the ratio of spam posts to all posts (or to other indicators of site activity level) for each site.

Comment: Where's ServerFault in that chart? I thought ServerFault was the next biggest SE site after SuperUser?

Comment: @404 I was actually going off of [traffic](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic), but it looks like Ask Ubuntu has passed ServerFault even for that. I wonder when that happened...